# Get the min width of the same class elements in jquery /css / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<img class = "draggable moveable" id = "1" style="width:20px;" >...</img>
<img class = "draggable printable" id = "2" style="width:50px;" >...</img>
<img class = "draggable moveable" id = "3" style="width:10px;" >...</img>
```

For the case above, how to implement the jquery/css selector to get the minimum width of the same class?(which is 10px in this case)

```
$('.draggable').('min:width');
```

are there such synatx? thanks

Comment: also , if the case is not width but left attribute, then it may have a negative number, please beware that in suggested solution, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such syntax, you can sort the element according to their width and use `first` method:

```
$('.draggable').sort(function(a, b){
   return $(a).width() > $(b).width(); 
}).first();
```

http://jsbin.com/igovaw/1/edit

Note that `img` element doesn't have closing tag.

If you want to get the minimum width and not the element you can use `map` method:

```
var w = $('.draggable').map(function(){
   return $(this).width(); 
}).get();

var min = Math.min.apply(null, w);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var minwidth = undefined;
$('.draggable').each(function () {
    width = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
    if (minwidth === undefined || width < minwidth) {
        minwidth = width;
    }
});
```